# React/JSX - iterating JSON object & nest every X items in .row

Tags: json, reactjs, object, nested

There must be an easy answer to this but I can't seem to find one.

JSON: -

```
{
  1: {
    'desc' : 'desc1',
    'title' : 'title 1',
  },
  2: {
    'desc' : 'desc2',
    'title' : 'title 2',
  },
  3: {
    'desc' : 'desc3',
    'title' : 'title 3',
  },
  4: {
    'desc' : 'desc4',
    'title' : 'title 4',
  },
  5: {
    'desc' : 'desc5',
    'title' : 'title 5',
  },
  6: {
    'desc' : 'desc6',
    'title' : 'title 6',
  },
};
```

So basically I want to iterate this object and have every 3 items nest in a .row class div like this: -

```
<div class='row'>
    <div>desc1 : title1</div>
    <div>desc2 : title2</div>
    <div>desc3 : title3</div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
    <div>desc4 : title4</div>
    <div>desc5 : title5</div>
    <div>desc6 : title6</div>
</div>
```

Now I understand how I can simple render() this in a component: -

```
{
    Object.keys(JSONObject).map(key => <TheComponent key={key} details={JSONObject[key]} />)
}
```

However, I am stumped as to how I can split this into 2 rows of 3 items and nest each of the 3 items in the .row div.

Any help greatly appreciated. I am relatively new to ES6/ReactJS and eager to get past the teething problems.

Answer (score 0):

One way of looking at this is to split the array up first into chunks, then working with that.

So you could get your initial array;

```
var ar1 = Object.keys(JSONObject);
```

Then chunk it up

```
var ar2 = [];
var i, j, chunk = 3;
for (i = 0, j = ar1.length; i < j; i += chunk) {    
    ar2.push(ar1.slice(i, i+chunk));    
}
```

This will then give you `ar2` which is an array of arrays. You could then either loop through this and output the level one array with the rows, then the level 2 array with the inner html.

See this basic bit of code on [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/heniraxeki/edit?js,console) to demo the chunking

Answer (score 0):

I did something very similar, so here is the code I used:

```
let rowCount = 0;
let rows = [];
Object.keys(JSONObject).forEach((k, i) => {
    // this just makes sure there is always an array initialised 
    rows[rowCount] = rows[rowCount] || []; 
    // now we add into the current row a component
    rows[rowCount].push(
        <TheComponent
            key={k}
            details={JSONObject[key]}
        />
    );

    if ((i + 1) % 3 === 0) { // the 3 here is how many items you want per row!!
        // if we can perfectly divide the current position by 3
        // we have filled a row, so now increment the row
        rowCount++;
    }
});
```

This will give you an array of arrays:

```
[
    [ <TheComponent key=1 />, <TheComponent key=2 /> <TheComponent key=3 /> ]
    [ <TheComponent key=4 /> ... ]
    [ .... ]
]
```

Then you can render like this:

```
render() {
    const rows = this.groupRows(); // this is the function above

    // ar below is a single array of <TheComponent ... /> so looks like:
    // [ <TheComponent ... />, ... ]
    return (
      <div>
        { rows.map((ar, i) => <div className="row"> { ar } </div>) }
      </div>
    );
}
```

### Addendum

I actually created a component to do this for me, so I could use it like so:

```
render() {
    return (
        <Grouper>
            { Object.keys(JSONObject).map(k => <TheComponent key={k} details={ JSONObject[key] } />) }
        </Grouper>
    );
}
```

And what the `<Grouper />` component did was `React.Children.forEach(...)` grouping them using the code I have above. Which meant all that component scaffolding code was nicely abstracted away from the business view logic.

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys. I ended up creating a chunkify utility with the chunk number passed as a param then having a function in the component to chunk the JSON and render the components in each chunk in a parent div. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
 let arrTheComponent = [], arrJson = [];

    Object.keys(JSONObject).map(key => {

        arrJson.push(JSONObject[key]);
        if (arrJson.length === 3) {
            arrTheComponent.push(<TheComponent json={arrJson} />);
            arrJson = [];
        }
    })
```

Display the component

```
export const TheComponentList = () => {

    let arrTheComponent = [], arrJson = [];

    Object.keys(JSONObject).map(key => {

        arrJson.push(JSONObject[key]);
        if (arrJson.length === 3) {
            arrTheComponent.push(<TheComponent json={arrJson} />);
            arrJson = [];
        }
    })

    return (<div>
        {arrTheComponent}
    </div>);
}
```